# @PostConstruct Annotation and JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, myfaces

I have a problem on my project implemented on  JSF 1.2 (MyFaces 1.2.6) and integrated Spring.

The problem is about @PostConstruct annotation. 
It is executed but I see that it is executed before managed properties are populated.
First I suspect about managed properties taken from Spring context so I tried a simple integer managed property, I see it is not populated too.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which managed properties are you talking about? JSF managed properties as in `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml` or Spring managed properties? The former *must* be set before `@PostConstruct`, otherwise it's a major bug in MyFaces. If the later, then I don't know. I don't do Spring. By the way, JSF 2.x is entirely different from JSF 1.x, so I've removed the incorrect tag.

Comment: Yes, JSF managed properties as in <managed-property> in faces-config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved it. It is a bug of MyFaces 1.2.6.

It is resolved when upgraded to 1.2.7